# UIView is not updating when popToViewController on NavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigationController where I `pushViewController` two viewcontrollers, `OneViewController` and `TwoViewController`. When I rotating the device on the pushed `TwoViewController`, and then `popToViewController` (see code) back to `OneViewController` the view on `OneViewController` is not updated / rotated.

Update: I have created a small sample project, where I have added a navigationController and two ViewControllers - and then doing the same thing. That is actually working, the only different I can think of is that the Views in my application that fails, is that I load the views from Xib files.

All the constraints in the view is setup in Interface Builder - and saved to the xib file.

I have the following in the view that I reference in Interface Builder as the ViewControllers view:

```
func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
    return nib.instantiate(
        withOwner: self,
        options: nil).first as? UIView
}

override public func awakeFromNib() {
 super.awakeFromNib()
 // Not setting up any constraints in code of setting any frame here.
}
```

[image]

If I then rotate on the `OneViewController` it then renders fine.

Do you know why it is not updating when using popToViewController?

```
        let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers
        for aViewController in viewControllers {
            if aViewController is OneViewController {

                    aViewController.view.updateConstraints()
                    aViewController.view.setNeedsDisplay()
                    aViewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    aViewController.view.setNeedsLayout()

                self.navigationController!.popToViewController(aViewController, animated: true)
                break
            }
        }
```

On the view I have also tried this:

```
override func viewWillShow(passingInAnyObject: AnyObject?) {
    self.updateConstraints()
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

Comment: why not do it in viewWillAppear of OneViewController?

Comment: what do u mean by view on OneViewController not updated ? What are u updating ? If u are talking only about rotation then have u declared supportedInterfaceOrientations in OneViewController/SecondViewController u mentioned ?

Comment: What are you manually / explicitly changing when the device rotates? If you're using auto-layout (which I assume you are since you've tried `.updateConstraints()`) you shouldn't *need* to do anything in code when the device rotates.

Comment: I am not changing anything - just popToViewController.

Comment: OK... do you have all the elements in `OneViewController` arranged with constraints? Or are you setting `.frame` on them? What happens if you simply use `self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)`?

Comment: Yes I am using constraints. Good idea, I will try to pop the specific view controller.

Comment: Just updated the question("update")

Comment: Hmm... so, when are you loading the views from XIBs? In `viewDidLoad()`? And when / how are you setting their frames? And are you setting frames with CGRects? Or are you adding constraints?

Comment: I am reference the view from IB. I update the question again :-) Thanks for you questions

Comment: Also I tried popViewController, but still not updating the view.

Comment: See if you can put together a simple example of what you're doing that is resulting in bad layout updating, and post the project either via file-sharing or on GitHub or similar. It's really difficult to guess what might be happening when only seeing little, unrelated snippets.

Comment: Yes, I agree - thanks, and  I will do that.

Comment: @DonMag I just answered my question. A: aViewController.view.frame.size = UIScreen.main.bounds.size. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Call the functionality which you want to update on the viewcontroller to which you pop in viewWillAppear method:

```
   override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated) 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Super strange, but the following solved the problem:

Setting: `aViewController.view.frame.size = UIScreen.main.bounds.size`

Change the following:

```
   let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers
    for aViewController in viewControllers {
        if aViewController is OneViewController {

                aViewController.view.updateConstraints()
                aViewController.view.setNeedsDisplay()
                aViewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                aViewController.view.setNeedsLayout()

            self.navigationController!.popToViewController(aViewController, animated: true)
            break
        }
    }
```

TO:

```
       let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers
        for aViewController in viewControllers {
            if aViewController is OneViewController {

            aViewController.view.frame.size = UIScreen.main.bounds.size

                self.navigationController!.popToViewController(aViewController, animated: true)
                break
            }
        }
```